# Hostname Hacking

Tags: configuration, onion-services, deanonymization, whonix, server

How do I protect against this vulnerability?

https://mascherari.press/dark-web-diaries-hostname-hacking/

```
> torify curl -H 'Host: localhost' http://myonionaddress.onion
```

It reveals another onion hosted on my server. I'm using nginx in Debian/whonix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple method, for `nginx` at least, is to just set the onion services to listen on different addresses in your server stanzas, and likewise configure your torrc to also do that

```
server {
    servername _; #Default/catch-all server, stock "nginx" index.html
    listen 80;
    #... Config Crap Here ...
}

server {
    servername oniona.onion;
    listen 127.0.0.2;
    #... Config Crap Here ...
}

server {
    servername onionb.onion;
    listen 127.0.0.3;
    #... Config Crap Here ...
}

#... Repeat as required ...
```

And edit your `torrc` to reflect this, e.g.

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/oniona
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.2:80
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/onionb
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.3:80
# Repeat as required
```